# How to use WinRAR through Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd, winrar

I need some help with a batch file because I am stumped on WinRAR in Batch, as I haven't done/used it before.

Here is the TREE of my Folders including the batch file:
[image]

- Each RAR file has the same Directory folder name("vegies" folder).

I would like to be able to extract/copy all folders/subfolders inside of each .rar from `"Example/Program_Ex/vegie"` back one directory into `"Example/Program_Ex/vegies"` (Dont forget the folder "vegies" already exists in each RAR which I cannot change as these automatically update themselves.)

So basically with a batch file I would like to:

```
extract "Example/Program_Ex/vegie/random.rar" to "Example/Program_Ex/vegies"
extract "Example/Program_Ex/vegie/random2.rar" to "Example/Program_Ex/vegies"
extract "Example/Program_Ex/vegie/random3.rar" to "Example/Program_Ex/vegies"
extract "Example/Program_Ex/vegie/random4.rar" to "Example/Program_Ex/vegies"
extract "Example/Program_Ex/vegie/random5.rar" to "Example/Program_Ex/vegies"
```

I also am trying to not specify a drive, more or less because the batch file will be in the correct folder instead using something such as "CD" or "PATH"?

I have looked at some examples around the web and on here of coarse, but I am still unsure the best way to go about this.

The closest example I can find would be this:

```
@echo off

set destinationRAR=destination_winrar_file
set source=source_folder_path

"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -ep1 -esh -ibck -m0 -r -t %destinationRAR% %source%
```

(Above from http://fredy-invayne.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/example-winrar-batch-file.html)

Can anyone help give examples on how to implement my question please?

Comment: Do you want to copy the archives or to extract their contents? Please note that the `a` WinRAR command in your example is for *adding* files to an (either new or existing) archive.

Comment: Sorry @Andriy M, i have edited my question, i want to extract their contents, the bottom example above is the closest example i can find not necessarily the one i am after. Cheers.

Comment: 7Zip command line is good for this job.

Comment: 7-Zip support older versions of windows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
    for %%a in (
        "%~dp0Example\Program_Ex\vegie\*.rar"
    ) do unrar x "%%~fa" -w "%~dp0Example\Program_Ex" -o+
```

For each file in the indicated path under the folder in where the batch file is stored, extract the content of the file indicating target folder and selecting that `existing files must be overwritten`.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all the archives with a single invocation of WinRAR:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x "%~dp0Program_Ex\vegie\random*.rar" "%~dp0Program_Ex\"
```

The last argument in the above command line specifies the target folder for all the archives. You may want to add the `-o+` switch (must go just after `x`) to specify that all files should be overwritten:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -o+ "%~dp0Program_Ex\vegie\random*.rar" "%~dp0Program_Ex\"
```

If you omit it, the archiver will ask you what to do with existing files, if any.